# How to pass parameters to a inquirer question?

Tags: javascript, promise, inquirerjs

How to pass parameters to the  inquirer questions, so that i can set the values of a question object based on either values from previous questions or from code outside the prompt?

The only way i can see of achieving this if based on answer of a previous question is to nest the inquirer prompt calls

```js
const inquirer = require('inquirer');

function getPath(){
    return {
        'system1':`system1path`,
        'system2':`system2path`,
        'system3':`system3path`
    }
}

inquirer.prompt([
     {
        type: 'list',
        name: 'testSystem',
        message: 'Which system do you want to run?',
        choices: ['system1', 'system2', 'system3']
    },
    {
        type: 'fuzzypath',
        name: 'searchTestSuite',
        excludePath: nodePath => nodePath.startsWith('node_modules'),
        itemType: 'any',
        rootPath: getPath()['< answer from question(testSystem) >'],
        message: 'Select a target directory :',
        default: `system1path`,
        suggestOnly: false,
        depthLimit: 6,
    },

]).then(answers => {
    console.log(answers);
});
```

Expected result :
If you select testSystem = system2
You should get rootPath = system2Path , without nesting the inquirer prompts or by using `when`function (since `when` seems to be dealing with boolean values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it by nesting, but changing from `Promise.then` to `async-await` makes it more readable. Inquirer.js uses promises, hence you can use await to capture prompt answers and by issuing multiple prompts you can save the state between prompts. See code below.

PS: I've removed the `default: ...,` parameter from fuzzypath because it yields the default value despite it beign outside the root path.

```js
const inquirer = require('inquirer');
inquirer.registerPrompt('fuzzypath', require('inquirer-fuzzy-path'))

const system1path = ...;
const system2path = ...;
const system3path = ...;

function getPath(){
    return {
        'system1': `${system1path}`,
        'system2': `${system2path}`,
        'system3': `${system3path}`
    };
}

(async function () {
    const {testSystem} = await inquirer.prompt({
        type: 'list',
        name: 'testSystem',
        message: 'Which system do you want to run?',
        choices: ['system1', 'system2', 'system3']
    });
    const {searchTestSuite} = await inquirer.prompt({
        type: 'fuzzypath',
        name: 'searchTestSuite',
        excludePath: nodePath => nodePath.startsWith('node_modules'),
        itemType: 'any',
        rootPath: getPath()[testSystem],
        message: 'Select a target directory :',
        suggestOnly: false,
        depthLimit: 6,
    });
    console.log({testSystem, searchTestSuite});
})();
```